# How would I create a fork and create a PR for a local repository?

Tags: github, fork

We are providing a code drop to our customer via GitHub and unable to fork and create a PR.

Locally, we developed some code, with a long commit history. Now, our customer is asking us to provide the code to him.

As far as I understand, the standard practice is that the customer would create a repo, I'd fork it, populate with our local commits and create PR to the customer, so he could review and accept our work.

This is where the problems start:

- If the customer creates the repository populated with README, I fork it successfully but I'm unable to create a PR because of the different commit history.
- If the customer creates an empty (without the README.md) repo, GitHub doesn't allow me to fork this empty repo.

How would I pass the repository to the customer, so he would be able to review, comment and accept our work?

Comment: Just push your (local) repo to the customer repo: `git push -f <customer repo url>`...

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround would be for you to:

- fork the client's repo (with a README)
- fetch that fork (small) history, declared as "client"

  ```
  git remote add client https://github.com/client/repo
  git fetch client
  ```
- rebase your working branch on that imported fork

  ```
  git switch yourBranch
  git rebase client/master
  git push --force
  ```
- make your PR.

That would mean for you and your colleagues the need to reset yourBranch to the new history created by the rebase.